# How do I echo username in profile page with PHP?

Tags: php, post, get, echo

So I want to echo the users' "username" on their profile. It's not working when I user this piece of code. why? Help please i echo'ed this on my page    `<?php   echo "<td>" . $row['username'] . "</td>";?>` but didn't work

```
<?php
if (!session_id()) session_start();
if (!$_SESSION['logon']){ 
    header("Location:login.php");
    die();
}
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("test", $con);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `users` where username='$username'");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
$username = $row['username'];
?>
```

Comment: create username as session when login

Comment: Please try to `print_r()` or `var_dump()` your results before going in here. I think you will know the problem once you see what's really going on.

Answer (score 0):

Try `<?php echo $username; ?>`

Answer (score 0):

Try `mysql_fetch_assoc` function without `while` loop:

```
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

<?php echo "<td>" . $row['username']; . "</td>"; ?>
```

Comment: still didn't fetch the username but took off some errors. do you think I have something else wrong in my code?

Comment: Could you dump it with `var_dump($row);`? Be sure isnt empty!