# Best way to echo a username on every page with sessions?

Tags: php, mysql, session

I've figured out how to make a working registration form and a login form. I also have a quiz that publishes scores to a database when a user is logged in. Now I'm trying to figure out how to capture the username of a user who's logged in and make it available on other pages of my site.

Judging from the discussion @ [How do I echo username in profile page with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24584165/php-how-do-i-echo-username-in-profile-page) it looks like I should just write a simple database query in the first page of every section. But is there a more efficient way?

To illustrate, my registration and login forms are located at mysite/admin, while my tests are at mysite/test.

Here's the code from my login page:

```
<?php if( !isset( $_SESSION['user_id'] ) ): ?>
<h2>Login Here</h2>
<form action="/admin/login/login-submit.php" method="post">
<fieldset>
<label for="username">Username</label>
<input type="text" id="username" name="username" value="" maxlength="20" />
<br>
<label for="password">Password</label>
<input type="text" id="password" name="password" value="" maxlength="20" />
<br>
<input type="submit" value="→ Login" />
</fieldset>
</form>
```

And here's the code from login-submit.php:

```
if(isset( $_SESSION['user_id'] ))
{
 $message = 'Users is already logged in';
}
/*** check that both the username, password have been submitted ***/
if(!isset( $_POST['username']))
{
 $message = 'Please enter a valid username and password';
}
/*** check the username has only alpha numeric characters ***/
elseif (ctype_alnum($_POST['username']) != true)
{
 /*** if there is no match ***/
 $message = "Username must be alpha numeric";
}
/*** check the password has only alpha numeric characters ***/
elseif (ctype_alnum($_POST['password']) != true)
{
    /*** if there is no match ***/
    $message = "Password must be alpha numeric";
}
else
{
/*** if we are here the data is valid and we can insert it into    database ***/
$username = filter_var($_POST['username'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$password = filter_var($_POST['password'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

/*** now we can encrypt the password ***/
$password = sha1( $password );
// $phpro_password = sha1( $phpro_password );

// DATABASE CONNECTION

try
{
    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$mysql_hostname;dbname=$mysql_dbname",   $mysql_username, $mysql_password);
    /*** $message = a message saying we have connected ***/

    /*** set the error mode to excptions ***/
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    /*** prepare the select statement ***/
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT user_id, username, password FROM     g1_members 
                WHERE username = :username AND password = :password");
    /*** bind the parameters ***/
    $stmt->bindParam(':username', $username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(':password', $password, PDO::PARAM_STR, 40);

    /*** execute the prepared statement ***/
    $stmt->execute();

    /*** check for a result ***/
    $user_id = $stmt->fetchColumn();

    /*** if we have no result then fail boat ***/
    if($user_id == false)
    {
            $message = 'Login Failed';
    }
    /*** if we do have a result, all is well ***/
    else
    {
            /*** set the session user_id variable ***/
            $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user_id;

            /*** tell the user we are logged in ***/
            $message = 'You are now logged in';
    }


}
catch(Exception $e)
{
    /*** if we are here, something has gone wrong with the database     ***/
    $message = 'We are unable to process your request. Please try again  later.';
 }
}
```

I added this simple query, which captures a user's username in $Username:

```
$stm = $pdo->prepare("SELECT username
 FROM g1_members
 WHERE user_id = :user_id");
 $stm->execute(array(
 'user_id'=>$user_id
));

 while ($row = $stm->fetch())
{
 $Username = $row['username'];
}
```

So do I need to add the same query in every section - e.g. mysite/topics, mysite/people, etc. - or is there a better way of doing it?

Comment: so put the user name into the session and echo it where you like?

Comment: Don't use `sha1` for password hashing - it is not slow enough, and there's no salting. Use `password_hash` instead, which uses a slow algorithm that incorporates salting for free.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you run this code:

```
 $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user_id;
```

You can add the user name as an additional session variable, like:

```
 $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
```

Which is already set in your code.